# How can I do this all in one query? Nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate

I have a list of Ids and I want to get all the rows back in one query. As a list of objects(So a List of Products or whatever).

I tried

```
public List<TableA> MyMethod(List<string> keys)
{
    var query = "SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE Keys IN (:keys)";
    var a = session.CreateQuery(query).SetParameter("keys", keys).List();
   return a; // a is a IList but not of TableA. So what do I do now?
}
```

but I can't figure out how to return it as a list of objects. Is this the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<TableA> result = session.CreateQuery(query)
                             .SetParameterList("keys", keys)
                             .List<TableA>();
```

Comment: @binaryhowl - It is giving me back an IList when I do that not a List.

Comment: @binaryhowl - I did a cast to a list (List<TableA>) not sure if that is the way to go but I get this error when I try to run it -Exception of type 'Antlr.Runtime.NoViableAltException' was thrown. near line 1, column 7

Comment: If you want a concrete List<T>, just return result.ToList(), although the best way would be for you to change the method to return an IEnumerable<TableA> or at least an IList<T>

Comment: @binaryhowl - Well normally I would use ToList() but I don't see that method. It will not give me that as a choice.

Comment: @chobo2 - Include the System.Linq reference.

Comment: @binaryhowl  - Ya I have that already. I can use ToList() on other methods but not that one

Comment: @binaryhowl - I think I know why I am using SetParameter not SetParameterList. However I still get that error what to my understanding is an sql parsing error. What is wrong with my query?

Answer (score 0):

Howeever there could be a limitation in this query if number of ":keys" exceed more than 1000 (incase of oracle not sure with other dbs) so i would recommend to use ICriteria instead of CreateQuery- native sqls.

Do something like this,

```
[TestFixture]
    public class ThousandIdsNHibernateQuery
    {
        [Test]
        public void TestThousandIdsNHibernateQuery()
        {
            //Keys contains 1000 ids not included here.
            var keys = new List<decimal>();

            using (ISession session = new Session())
            {
                var tableCirt = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(TableA));


                if (keys.Count > 1000)
                {
                    var listsList = new List<List<decimal>>();

                    //Get first 1000.
                    var first1000List = keys.GetRange(0, 1000);

                    //Split next keys into 1000 chuncks.
                    for (int i = 1000; i < keys.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if ((i + 1)%1000 == 0)
                        {
                            var newList = new List<decimal>();
                            newList.AddRange(keys.GetRange(i - 999, 1000));
                            listsList.Add(newList);
                        }

                    }

                    ICriterion firstExp = Expression.In("Key", first1000List);
                    ICriterion postExp = null;

                    foreach (var list in listsList)
                    {
                        postExp = Expression.In("Key", list);
                        tableCirt.Add(Expression.Or(firstExp, postExp));
                        firstExp = postExp;

                    }

                    tableCirt.Add(postExp);
                }
                else
                {
                    tableCirt.Add(Expression.In("key", keys));

                }

                var results = tableCirt.List<TableA>();
            }

        }
    }
```